# Drawing animation 3D

Tags: animation, drawing

This is a great drawing animation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uG4xe9cNpP0

On which I don't know how to achieve the following:

1)Moving background creating the sensation of distance between the drawing and the background.

2)Soft moving of the camera from one section of the drawing to the another.

3)How the size of some images like the text bubbles changes from 0 to their final size, lovely effect.

Any hint of Sw and technique used?

Regards.

Comment: Paralax can be created with nearly any animation application there is no indication it is 3D. The application could be anything but again I would tip After Effects. But it could be anything certainly after effect isnt the best one for this job.

Comment: jooja I tried to make something like this in After Effects without success, obviously I'm a noob on it but still no hint how he gets this life drawing effect with the other animations on the video. Which sw would you say is the better for this?